# How can I print specific tags from a html file with Python?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, python-3.x, tags

How can I print all the `<a>` tags in [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/vl5o954r3cnsdkw/text.html?dl=1&token_hash=AAGBoAnC1kBs_HiEbdcbWkVL6mHEoYokdjCRNq-SwxvyAA) html file with Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`beautifulsoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('text.html') as input_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(input_file)
    a_links = soup.find_all('a')
    for link in a_links:
        print link
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [re](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://docs.python.org/library/re.html&ei=wv8xU7nwOY7LsQSjioDQAw&usg=AFQjCNGHDIDJowa8fzj7t0PjwX8tNfn-Ug&sig2=MBEheKksvjVYjINAW-7rAA&bvm=bv.63587204,d.cWc) or [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).  Either of those should be able to help you with what you need depending on whether or not you want to actually include the tags.